# Change URL with return view on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I use REST api for CRUD.
When I Use return redirect after CRUD, Laravel does not send me variable with
I don't want use session.
My code

```
return redirect("inventories")->with([ 'Tab' => 5,'flag' => 'success', 'flagMsg' => 'delete_successful', 'Inventories' => $Inventory]);
```

and when I use return view, Laravel send me variable but URL not change
and I want redirect and change URl
for example my URL is `/inventories/2/edit` and after update send me to  `/inventories/update` and I want to redirect `inventories`

Comment: REST API's also don't redirect you!

Comment: You already use the session when you do `with()` on `redirect()`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin have to laugh because I have your best practices open right now!

Comment: @ThomasMoors it's a small world. )

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I don't want use session. because I have many variable and ....  Is there any way?

Comment: @paranoid if you have many variables, you can just save an array of these variables. Or you can pass these to a view and then read, but using session is so much better.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Or you can pass these to a view and then read.... can you more explaine?

Comment: @paranoid well, you can return a view and pass these variables with `return view('some.view', ['var1' => $var1])`. Then you'll need to pass these to a controller with next request and then pass to another view etc. But that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use link_to_route() and link_to_action() methods too. (source)

link_to_route take three parameters (name, title and parameters). you can use it like following:

```
link_to_route('api.GetAPI', 'get api', [ 
  'page_no' => $page_no,
  'id' => $id
]);
```

If you want to use an action, link_to_action() is very similar but it uses action name instead of route.

```
link_to_action('ApiController@getApi', 'get api', [ 
  'page_no' => $page_no,
  'id' => $id
]);
```